# Get only the input type text not the chooser fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
'<tr>
<td class="label" width="40%"> Business Unit Code </td>
<td class='inputField">
<input type="text" value name="attribute1" size="20" readonly     maxLength="25">"&nbsp;"
<input class="button" name="button1" type ="button" size="200" value=".." alt="..." onclick="function1{};">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label" width ="40%" >style</td>
<td class="inputField">
<select name="attribute2">
<option selected value></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label" width="40%"> car line </td>
<td class='inputField">
<input type="text" name="attribute3" size="null" value>
</td>
</tr>`
```

In the ablove code I want to get only the input field "attribute3". If I am trying use the javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('inputfield')" it is getting attribute1 and attribute3. But I want the values of attribute3 to validate the values.
Please provide the javascript validation code.

Comment: You have invalid html in few places. ex: <td class='inputField">

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`getElementsByName`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)**

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("attribute3");
```

> Please note that it returns A NodeList object, representing a
>   collection of elements with the specified name. The elements in the
>   returned collection are sorted as they appear in the source code. So if you want to validate its value then you might need to do `document.getElementsByName("attribute3")[0].value`

So I would suggest it will be good if you give `id`s to your `elements` and use `getElementById` which returns single `element` as `id`s will be unique in `DOM`

---

**UPDATE**

To get all the `input type=text` elements use **[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

**For Ex:**

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#yourformid input[type=text]");
for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
{
    //get the value using nodes[i].value
}
```

Comment: t is a dynamic form and i need to get all the fields which are input type text...how can i get all the fields .

Comment: i tried using queryselectorAll but it is getting  attribute1  is in the nodes list

Comment: If you want only `attribute3` then use `document.querySelectorAll("#yourformid input[name=attribute3]");`

Answer (score 2):

According to the comment @Guruprasad Rao, you need all input text fields.

In JavaScript you can do:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'text') {
        console.log(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

In Jquery you can do:

```
$("input:text")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Selector:  document.querySelectorAll('[name="attribute3"]')
  Value : document.querySelectorAll('[name="attribute3"]')[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure JavaScript you may consider the following:

```
//<![CDATA[
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();

var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
function N(name, element){
  var e = element || doc;
  return e.getElementsByName(name);
}
function cN(className, element){
  var e = element || doc;
  if(e.getElementsByClassName){
    return e.getElementsByClassName(className);
  }
  else{
    var x = e.getElementsByTagName('*'), a = [];
    for(var i=0,l=x.length; i<l; i++){
      var t = x[i];
      if(t.className === className){
        a.push(t);
      }
      return a;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
/* console.log(N('attribute3')[0].value);
  or
   console.log(cN('inputField')[2].firstChild.value);
*/
}
//]]>
```

Of course, the second commented out `console.log` depends if your `.firstChild` is really the Element and not a text Node.

If you want Every text element's value on the form, using code from above, you could do this:

```
function getTextInputVals(formElement){
  var els = formElement.elements, a = [];
  for(var i=0,l=els.length; i<l; i++){
    var e = els[i];
    if(e.type === 'text'){
      a.push(e.value);
    }
  }
  return a;
}
// console.log(getTextInputVals(doc.form[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the below methods and it worked ..thanks for the quick response

```
function analyseFreetextField() {
    var fieldValue = "";
    var fieldName = "";
    var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i ++) {
        if (inp[i].className == 'inputField') {
            if (inp[i].childElementCount == 1 && inp[i].firstElementChild.type == 'text' ) {
               fieldName = inp[i].firstElementChild.name;
               fieldValue = inp[i].firstElementChild.value;
               if (!alphanumeric(fieldValue)) {
                   alert('Invalid value detected' + fieldValue);
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```